# Struggling with some intuitive reasoning when regressing an I(0) variable against an I(1) variable

Tags: regression, stochastic-processes, stationarity, cointegration

Say we regress a noisy variable $y_t$ (i.e. $I(0)$) against a non-stationary variable $x_t$ (e.g. $I(1)$) as follows
\begin{equation}
y_t=\beta x_{t}+\varepsilon_t
\end{equation}
Then naturally the residuals of this regression $\varepsilon_t$ would be $I(1)$. Now let us consider that we have observed the nonstationary process $x_t$ and using earlier logic, we wish to generate a similar series $y_t$ by considering perturbations $\varepsilon_t$ that are $I(1)$. However, as $x_t$ is observed and hence fixed, $\varepsilon_t$ which is $I(1)$, +, $\beta x_{t}$ which are constants, add up to a $y_t$ process which is $I(1)$, as opposed to $I(0)$. Where does my lack of understanding/ flawed logic lie in this intuitive reasoning?